# How to Invert SVG text with appropriate kerning?

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

How can I invert (rotate 180 degrees) a text object so that the text is kerned appropriately?

My example uses Python and the svgwrite package, but my question seems about any SVG.

Suppose I use the following code:

```
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing()
dwg.add(dwg.text(fullName, (int(width/2.),gnameHeight), 
                    font_size=gnameFontSize, text_anchor="middle"))
```

The above code generates text looking like this:

[image: plain text]

`dwg.text()` objects accept a `rotate` parameter that is applied to all characters in a text string, so I've used the following code to reverse the string first:

```
pcRotate = [180]
ngap = 1

revFullName = fullName
rcl = []
for c in revFullName:
    rcl.append(c)
    for i in range(ngap):
        rcl.append(' ')

rcl.reverse()
revFullName = ''.join(rcl)

dwg.add(dwg.text(revFullName, (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight), 
                font_size=gnameFontSize, text_anchor="middle", rotate=pcRotate))
```

But, this produces the very ugly version below:

[image: rotated text]

and this is using an artificial space gap between characters to make it slightly less unreadable.

What's the best way to tap into whatever kerning is being used by standard text in this inverted situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rotate` attribute of a `<text>` element is intended for situations where you want to rotate individual characters.  If you want to rotate the whole text object then you should be using a `transform` instead.

http://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/mixins.html#transform-mixin

Comment: Thanks Paul!  so i'm trying this sort of thing now: `transString = 'rotate(180,center=(%s,%s))' % (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight)
 textGroup = svgwrite.container.Group(transform=transString)
 
 textGroup.add(dwg.text(fullName, (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight), 
     font_size=gnameFontSize, text_anchor="middle"))
 textGroup.add(dwg.text(loc, (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight- 2* gnameFontSize), 
     font_size=gnameFontSize, text_anchor="middle"))
 dwg.add(textGroup)`  but now i get "rotate(180,center=(250,240)) is not a valid attribute' ?!

Comment: A rotate transform attribute should look like this: `transform="rotate(180, 250,240)"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a self-answer, only to make formatting more clear. Two useful hints from @paul-lebeau happily acknowledged.

While the `svgwrite` package seems solid, its documentation is a bit thin. The two things I wish it had said:

1. The `rotate` attribute of a `<text>` element is intended for situations where you want to rotate individual characters. If you want to rotate the whole text object, then you should be using a [transform mixin](http://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/mixins.html#transform-mixin) instead.
2. If you need to center the transformed text with respect to some center (other that the default current user coordinate system), add two additional parameters `xctr,yctr`. This differs from the doc which calls for a single `center` argument that is a (2-tuple).

The correct code is:

```
pcRotate = 'rotate(180,%s,%s)' % (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight)
textGroup = svgwrite.container.Group(transform=pcRotate)

textGroup.add(dwg.text(fullName, (int(width/2.),pcnameHeight), 
                font_size=gnameFontSize, text_anchor="middle"))
dwg.add(textGroup)
```